# Plot.ly in R: Unwanted alphabetical sorting of x-axis

Tags: javascript, r, rstudio, plotly

I tried for hours, but I could not succeed. My data frame is simply

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("g","d","a","b","z",5,4,3,2,1),5,2))

library("plotly")
p <- plot_ly(data = df,x = ~V1,y = ~V2,type = "scatter",mode = "lines+markers") %>%
layout(title = "my title")
p
```

So, this give me

[image: myplot]

But I don't want x axis to be sorted alphabetically, I just want to keep the order as it is and see a decreasing graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, a matrix can only hold data of **one** class. Hence you have a matrix of strings that you are converting to a `data.frame`. Because by default `stringAsFactors = TRUE`, your character matrix is converted to a `data.frame` of `factor`'s, where the levels of your two columns are by default sorted. Alphabetically for `V1` and in increasing order for `V2`.

If you don't wish to modify the data directly to remedy the issue at the source - as pointed out in the other answers, you can altenatively use `plotly`'s `categoryorder =` argument inside `layout()` in the following way:

```
library(plotly)
xform <- list(categoryorder = "array",
              categoryarray = df$V1)

plot_ly(data = df,
        x = ~V1,
        y = ~V2,
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "lines+markers") %>%
        layout(title = "my title",
               xaxis = xform)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
> df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("g","d","a","b","z",5,4,3,2,1),5,2))
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
$ V1: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","d","g",..: 4 3 1 2 5
$ V2: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 5 4 3 2 1
> df$V1
[1] g d a b z
Levels: a b d g z
> df$V1 <- ordered(df$V1, c("g","d","a","b","z"))
> df$V1
[1] g d a b z
Levels: g < d < a < b < z
```